# Google Analytics - Approved Users at the backend

Tags: google-analytics

Just wanted to check few things based on the below scenario

"Number of users visit a specific website and they register themselves on that website using their email id. 
Once the users are registered, the admin team at the back end approves the registered email id(not all email id's get approved) by clicking on the "approved button" in the admin tool."

My questions are:

1. how to show the number of approved users in the GA report (please not approval is taking place in the back end by the admin)
2. how to capture the number of returning "approved" users on the website.